# Creating files for later usage in java

Tags: java, file

I am writing a Java application that writes a number of files, and later reads the files for their values. I am using InstallShield to install the application under `C:\Program Files`, and this is where the temporary files usually get created. However, when using Windows 7, the files are created under the users temporary folder instead, with a random name.

Here is my code...

```
File usersTemp = File.createTempFile("users", null,temp);
```

And this is the file that gets generated...

```
C:\Users\TP\AppData\Local\Temp\users2343200092608531612.tmp
```

As the file is generated with a random number, it makes it hard to retrieve the file back for processing. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can't you set the file name in some variable by calling `usersTemp.getAbsolutePath()` and use that string for later?

Comment: Yes, i tried that however if i close the program and run it again i do not have the variable already, it would be replaced with a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're running as a superuser (which you're probably not), you can only edit files in the user's home directory, which you can find with the `user.home` [system property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html):

```
System.getProperty("user.home")
```

So, if you wanted to save a file in your application's application data folder:

```
File appDataFolder = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Local Settings\\Application Data\\YourProgramName");
```

Then save things under that folder and they will stick around.

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason why you can't just save the files normally (naming them whatever you want)?  I've written many Java programs for Windows 7 and haven't had any problems saving files.

Just use a FileOutputStream or whatever method you usually use to save files.

Comment: the problem is my program is unable to create files under the C:\Program Files directory , and it is because of administrative rights if i am not wrong

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a Temp file is that it should only exist for a short period of time. It seems like you are wanting to create a file that will persist for a longer time, possibly remaining between runs of the application? If this is the case, you should be creating a file with a proper name...

```
new File("c:\filename.txt").createNewFile();
```

That way, you are able to choose a directory and a name that would be suitable, no matter what operating system you're running the application on.

Comment: hi , that is exactly what i think would work, however due to windows adminstrative rights i would get a java.io.IOException: Access is denied

Comment: You would need to choose a directory that the user has permissions to write to. Probably the only guaranteed way to do this is to use the users home directory, as suggested by @Brendan... `System.getProperty("user.home")`. All other directories potentially forbid write access.